# In slider I want to change style on current slide

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Accordion slider in wordpress. In my slider I have given image `opacity:0.7`. I am trying to remove this opacity on the current slider. I am new to Jquery.

This is Structure of my slider

```
<div id="accordion-slider-1">
    <div class="as-mask">
       <div class="as-panels">
           <div class="as-panel as-shadow as-opened">
            <img class="as-background" src="" />
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is active class is `.as-opened`

This is my custom CSS

```
.as-panel .as-shadow{
background-color:#fff;
}
.as-panel .as-shadow img{
opacity:0.9;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should give us some code to work?

Comment: question updated...

Comment: why you are not using !important

Answer (score 0):

```
.as-opened{
 opacity:0.7;
 transition:1s linear;

}
```

Here is a solution without jquery